# How can I find out whether you are using WinUI 2 or WinUI 3?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, uwp, winui, winui-3

Currently, I try to learn how to use UWP UI component, in WPF application.

I'm following the examples in https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/XamlIslands

However, may I know, how can I find out, whether the example is using WinUI 2, or WinUI 3?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at .csproj files. They don't seem to use Microsoft.UI.Xaml ("MUX") namespace, so they're not using any of these. They use Windows.UI.Xaml ("WUX", comes with Windows 10) and the Xaml islands for WPF toolkit (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost)

Comment: I think https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/XamlIslands/blob/master/NavigationViewInWPF/WPFXamlTemplate/MainWindow.xaml.cs is using Windows.UI.Xaml. NavigationView is only available in WinUI. But, I have no idea whether it is WinUI 2 or 3.

Comment: As I said, it's Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView (Windows, Platform), not  Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView (WinUI) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the [WPFXamlTemplate.csproj](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/XamlIslands/blob/master/NavigationViewInWPF/WPFXamlTemplate/WPFXamlTemplate.csproj) file, you'll see that it has a `<PackageReference>` to [Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls 6.0.0-preview5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls/6.0.0-preview5).

This is known as the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32) which is a separate project from [Win UI](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml).

It uses XAML Islands host the native UWP controls in the WPF application.

Comment: I was intent to develop WPF as it has less system restriction. But, I would also like to have modern & shinny UI. In that case, should I use Windows Community Toolkit, or WinUI 2, or WinUI 3 ? Thanks.

Comment: WinUI 3 eventually but it's not ready for production yet. For now, you should use the Windows Community Toolkit. WinUI 2 is only compatible with UWP.